# What is going on with my wiring!

Tags: electrical, wiring

I am replacing 2 old pendant lights over a kitchen island. The new fixtures only have 2 black wires- not labeled.
The first box coming out of the ceiling has two sets of wires (= 2 white wires and 2 black wires). The second box in the ceiling only has one set of wires (= 1 white wire and 1 black wire).

The first way I tried to install was one black/black, one black/white on the double wire box and capped the extra white and black separately, and black/black and black/white on the single wire box. This worked and the double fixture box turned on but the single wire box did not.

I then tried to pair up the extra black and white wire together and cap them. That tripped the breaker.
I also tried switching the two black fixture wires on each of them. Neither worked.

Please help!

Comment: Can you return it to how it was originally wired... before you disconnected everything?

Answer (score 1):

> The first way I tried to install was one black/black, one black/white
> on the double wire box and capped the extra white and black
> separately, and black/black and black/white on the single wire box.
> This worked and the double fixture box turned on but the single wire
> box did not.

The single wire box gets it's power from the double wire box, The second set of wires in the first box are going to the second box. (*Power comes in on one set of wires and goes out on the other set of wires*)

In the first box the blacks go together with the black from the light, joined  with a wire nut.
The whites  go together with the other black from the light, joined  with a wire nut. The bare ground wires go together with a wire nut.

Is there no green  ground wire on the fixtures? If there is they attach to the bare grounds in each box.

Since you are not dead yet, i will assume you know to turn off the breaker and **TEST** for power **BEFORE** you proceed